# USB device not detected in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.10

I have Ubuntu12.10 installed. But none of my USB ports detects any USB device. But the same USB is detected in Windows OS . How to detect USB device in my Ubuntu system ?

Output of `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

O/p of `lsusb` :
`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

O/p of `lsmod` :

```
Module                  Size  Used by
usb_storage            39350  0 
i915                  457161  0 
drm_kms_helper         45271  1 i915
drm                   230463  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
bnep                   17707  2 
rfcomm                 37276  0 
parport_pc             31968  0 
ppdev                  12817  0 
bluetooth             183228  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    63356  1 
snd_hda_intel          32515  3 
snd_hda_codec         111547  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80163  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25382  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
asus_nb_wmi            12622  0 
coretemp               13168  0 
snd_seq                51255  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
asus_wmi               19320  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13658  1 asus_wmi
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
kvm_intel             126745  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
psmouse                84843  0 
kvm                   357806  1 kvm_intel
serio_raw              13031  0 
mac_hid                13037  0 
microcode              18209  0 
snd                    61991  15 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
wmi                    18590  1 asus_wmi
soundcore              14599  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14036  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
video                  18847  1 i915
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40753  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
r8169                  55976  0
```

My flash drive is 8GB USB flash drive.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some more info, such as the output of `lspci`, `lsusb`, and `lsmod`. What sort of device are we talking about? Keyboard, flash drive, etc?

Comment: Is there any trace in `dmesg` after you plug in an USB device?

Answer (score 0):

Very Tricky situation. Maybe it's the USB flash drive which was designed to run only on windows.You did not mention the name of the brand of your usb flash drive.Sometimes some usb flash drives belonging to certain brands behave that way.